# Removing a specific entry/row from Core-Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm using core data in my app, and i'm confused when it comes to removing certain rows or entries from the core data storage.  I insert some products in to the storage like so:

```
NSManagedObject *Product = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[Product setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:id] forKey:@"pid"];
[Product setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:quantity] forKey:@"pquantity"];
```

This works fine for insertion. However, later in the app, I want to remove the entry where for example, the pid is 53. How would I go about removing only this row/entry?  The equivalent SQL would be something like:

```
DELETE from Product WHERE pid = '53'
```

I would greatly appreciate some example code, as I can't seem to figure this one out.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 41):

As @Nektarios said, you are dealing with objects here so you want to find an object that has a particular attribute value. You that with a fetch request and a predicate.

```
  NSNumber *soughtPid=[NSNumber numberWithInt:53];
  NSEntityDescription *productEntity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  NSFetchRequest *fetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [fetch setEntity:productEntity];
  NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pid == %@", soughtPid];
  [fetch setPredicate:p];
  //... add sorts if you want them
  NSError *fetchError;
  NSArray *fetchedProducts=[self.moc executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError];
  // handle error
```

The `fetchedProducts` array will contain all the objects of the entity `Product` whose `pid` attribute equals `soughtPid`. Note that the predicate fulfills the same function logically as the `where` clause in SQL.

Once you have the objects you just tell the context to delete them:

```
  for (NSManagedObject *product in fetchedProducts) {
    [context deleteObject:product];
  }
```

When you next save the context, the object's data will be deleted from the persistent store file.

Comment: I edit some code according to my requirement but this code works for me thanks @TechZen

Answer (score 14):

Like Sqlite's "DELETE from tableName WHERE condition", you have no single step to delete `MULTIPLE` objects from CoreData.

In **CoreData**, first you have to **fetch** objects that has to be deleted, using `NSFetchRequest` and `NSPredicate`

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"EntityName"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"propertyName == %@", value];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;//Get your ManagedObjectContext;
NSArray *result = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Then, you should **iterate** through every `NSManagedObject` and call `deleteObject:` from your `NSManagedObjectContext`.

```
if (!error && result.count > 0) {
    for(NSManagedObject *managedObject in result){
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
    }

    //Save context to write to store
    [managedObjectContext save:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Remember to think of Core Data as a graph and not a DB, so the concept of rows doesn't apply. Instead, you want to remove a specific object from the graph.

You used `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` to insert it.  Use `deleteObject:` to delete it, such as:

`[aContext deleteObject:aManagedObject];`

In your case,

`[context deleteObject:Product];`

Good luck

See Apple's [explanation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html)

Note: when you delete, depending on your scheme, that can have different implications.  For example it could delete everything further down the child-path of your Core Data object graph.  Make sure you think hard when designing your schema about how that should work.  If you set it up right, this can be a huge advantage to you.

Answer (score 6):

Use this method:

```
+ (void)Deletebeer:(NSString*)m_Beerid
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *productEntity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Beers" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetch setEntity:productEntity];
    NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"m_Beerid == %@", m_Beerid];
    [fetch setPredicate:p];
    //... add sorts if you want them
    NSError *fetchError;
     NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedProducts=[context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError];
    for (NSManagedObject *product in fetchedProducts) {
        [context deleteObject:product];
    }
    [context save:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
Entity  *entity = (Entity *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[entity setTimeStamp:[NSDate date]];
NSError *error;
if ([managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

}
[eventArray delete:<#(id)sender#>];

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with UITableView swipe to delete for a few day, eventually I got things done.

The tableview is populated by the data from core data object. Delegate methods has been used are:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSectin:(NSInteger)section**
{
   reture [_arrData count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionInTablesView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
  if(cell == nil){
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
  }
  cell.textLable.text = [_arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  return YES;
}

-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewRowAction *delete = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action,NSIndexPath *indexPath){


        //**************load address **************
        NSError *error;

        AppDelegate *sharedDelegate = [AppDelegate appDelegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [sharedDelegate managedObjectContext];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"data" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchReuqets = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lat == %@", [_arrLat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [fetchReuqets setPredicate:predicate];

        NSLog(@"delete %@",[_arrLat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

        [fetchReuqets setEntity:entity];
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchReuqets error:&error];
        NSLog(@"number of filtered objects=%ld",fetchedObjects.count);
        if(!error && fetchedObjects.count>0){
            for (NSManagedObject *addr in fetchedObjects){
                [context deleteObject:addr];
                NSLog(@"delete addr %@",addr);
            }
            [context save:&error];
        }
        //***************core data**************************
        [_arrData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView reloadData];

    }];
    delete.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return @[delete];
}
```

Hopefully help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Simple where DatabaseInfo is the name of my entity, where filename is an attribute

```
CoreAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDesc];

NSPredicate *pred= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(filename = %@)", @"Thankyou"];

[request setPredicate:pred];
NSManagedObject *matches = nil;

NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if([objects count] == 0)
{
    _label1.text=@"No Match Found";
}
else{
    matches = objects[0];

    [context deleteObject:matches]    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3:

```
         if let dataAppDelegatde = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {


                let mngdCntxt = dataAppDelegatde.persistentContainer.viewContext

                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ItemCart")

                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemId = %i", Int(currentItemID)!)
                print(currentItemID)

                fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
                do{
                    let result = try mngdCntxt.fetch(fetchRequest)

                    print(result.count)

                    if result.count > 0{
                        for object in result {
                            print(object)
                            mngdCntxt.delete(object as! NSManagedObject)
                        }
                    }
                }catch{

                }
            }
```

Comment: This code doesn't remove the row, but instead makes the `currentItemId` = 0. I am searching to delete the row instead.