# Find out indexPath of cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a few UITableViewCells with the labels Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4 and Test5. How can I find out the indexPath of the cell which displays Test3? I don't wanna touch the cell or do something like this. Thanks for your answers!

The cells:

[image]

Core Data model:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a class variable reference to the cell, and then in `cellForRow` assign the cell with the "Test3" label to your class variable.

```
var test3Cell: UITableViewCell?

// ...

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = ... // Declaration here

        // set up the cell

        if cell.textLabel?.text == "Test3" {
            self.test3Cell = cell
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing it at the cell level seems backwards — your data model (the table’s `UITableViewDataSource`) would seem much easier to query.

Comment: I use CoreData. `Test1` `Test2` `Test3` `Test4` and `Test5` is saved in `name` (see the image in my question). Do you know how to delete `Test3` from `name` without an indexPath?

Comment: My CoreData is rusty, but surely it will be easier to just query and delete. Maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524876/removing-a-specific-entry-row-from-core-data

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the label you can use `indexPathForRowAtPoint`.

```
let pointInTable = sender.convertPoint(theLabel.bounds.origin, toView: self.tableView)
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(pointInTable)
```

`indexPath` where indexPath is an optional.

Answer (score 0):

How are you populating the table? If you are populating the label in the cell of tableview using the content from an NSArray.. you can find the indexpath from the index of the item in the Array obj..

If not, the way i can think of is to loop through the table cells in the tableView

The table view responds to the below methods
    func numberOfSections() -> Int
    func numberOfRowsInSection(section: Int) -> Int

you can create an NSIndexPath instance using the above information for each row .. NSIndexPath(forRow: , inSection: )

get the UITableviewCell instance using
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

then you can check the text of label in the cell to see if it matches what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This method will check your current visible cells within the tableview and iterate through them looking for the text.

```
// Swift 1.2
// Store current visable cells in an array
let currentCells = tableView.visibleCells() as Array

 // Iterate through cells looking for a match
 for cell in currentCells {
    println (cell.textLabel?!.text)

    if cell.textLabel?!.text == "Test 3" {
        println("Test 3 Found")
    }
}


// Swift 2.0
// Store current visable cells in an array
let currentCells = tableView.visibleCells

// Iterate through cells looking for a match
for cell in currentCells where cell.textLabel?.text == "Test 3" {
    print("Test 3 found") 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I get an error in this line of code: `for cell in currentCells {` it says: `'() -> [AnyObject]' does not have a member named 'Generator'`. Do you know why?

Comment: My mistake, I didn't test the above with Swift 1.2. I've amended the post now to take this into account.